# "Undefined reference to" file which is not on the current direcory

Tags: c

I met error `` pintos/src/userprog/build/../../userprog/syscall.c:56: undefined reference to `exit' `` while working on a pintos project.

Below is part of directory tree that is related with error.

```
-lib
    -user
        -syscall.c
        -syscall.h
           
-userprog
    -syscall.c
```

(lib and userprog have same hierarchy.)

In userprog/syscall.c, The function exit is well-defined on both header file and c file.

```c
// lib/user/syscall.c
void
exit (int status)
{
  syscall1 (SYS_EXIT, status);
  NOT_REACHED ();
}
```

```c
// lib/user/syscall.h

void exit (int status) NO_RETURN;
```

But When I call exit on `userprog/syscall.c`, I meet error `undefined refrence to 'exit'`
I includede syscall.h in lib/user/ as `#include "lib/user/syscall.h"`

```c
// userprog/syscall.c

#include "lib/user/syscall.h"
void
foo()
{
   ...
   exit(-1); 
}
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You have two source files named syscall.c.  Non-zero odds that this confuses the dickens out of the toolchain with one object file overwriting the other.  Pick another name for the userprog file and ensure you link both.

Comment: Post the command line you use to build the project.

Comment: Linker might not find `lib/user/syscall.o`, check your `Makefile`.